# how to use mono debugger on visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono

i search a lot to find a mono debugger on visual studio and i find one of theme in the [monoDebugger.Net](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bafacd44-9b9d-446c-bc77-215595e69fd0) . as i searched in the net , i found that i should run monodebugger.monoserver.exe with mono before i can debug it in visual studio . now my problem is that, at first am i right by run monodebugger.monoserver.exe with mono ? if yes how can i run it because i did not found it in mono! and if i'm wrong how can i use monodebuger.net .

i'm try to run my c# program on rbpi using mono to compile it .